# How to check %match between 2 string in prestosql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, presto, soundex

What im looking for is I have 2 words
e.g.
'Family' and 'Family Tree'

then I would love to know that how much does both texts match to each others.

let say
'Family' and 'Family'   >> 100 %

not sure any workaround or not.

Thank you so much.

Comment: [tag:jquery] doesn't really go with those other tags - did you select the wrong tag?

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? Remove the non-related dbms tags.

Comment: Looks like you might want SOUNDEX/DIFFERENCE, maybe *Levenshtein distance*

Answer (score 0):

you can use like.

```
select * from tablename where fildname like '%Family%'
```

Result Give you all row in keyword is Family present.

Comment: OP is trying to determine how close the matches are, eg "Famali" = 70% (or so)

Comment: if you use First % in like condition then it's give result like starting that position. When use both %% then it's give result of related match string it's give 100% result.

Comment: Op is asking **How to check percentage match** - not how to find by substring

Answer (score 0):

For presto you can try looking into [`levenshtein_distance(string1, string2) → bigint`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#levenshtein_distance) built in function:

> Returns the Levenshtein edit distance of `string1` and `string2`, i.e. the minimum number of single-character edits (insertions, deletions or substitutions) needed to change `string1` into `string2`.

Or (though it seems less suitable) [`hamming_distance(string1, string2) → bigint`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#hamming_distance):

> Returns the Hamming distance of `string1` and `string2`, i.e. the number of positions at which the corresponding characters are different. Note that the two strings must have the same length.